# Get author custom image field URL to display on post page?

Tags: images

I'm using advanced custom fields and have setup an image field for my users to add an image in their profile. I'd need to display this image on post pages, so i've tried the following...

```
<?php
$attachment_id = the_author_meta('author_logo');
?>
<?php echo the_author_meta('author_logo'); ?>
<?php wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id )?> 
<?php wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ); ?>
```

The output is always the image attachment ID never the URL. What can I change to output the image path URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta):

> The the_author_meta Template Tag displays the desired meta data for a
>   user. If this tag is used within The Loop, the user ID value need not
>   be specified, and the displayed data is that of the current post
>   author. A user ID can be specified if this tag is used outside The
>   Loop.
>
> If the meta field does not exist, nothing is printed.
>
> NOTE: Use [get_the_author_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta) if you need to return (not display)
>   the information.

So, replace `the_author_meta()` with `get_the_author_meta()`. You can then use [wp_get_attachment_image()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) to get an image element ready for outputting to the page.

```
<?php 
$id = get_the_author_meta('author_logo');
if ($id) {
    echo wp_get_attachment_image($id);
}
?>
```